# Why is this code printing True and not False? (Is it due to matrix creation?)

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
image=[[1,1,1],[1,1,0],[1,0,1]]    
visited = [[False] * len(image[0])] * len(image)    
visited[0][0] = True
print((visited[1][0]))
```

Shouldn't the above python code print `False`? Why is the entire column being assigned as `True`?

Comment: You should probably be using numpy if you want 2D arrays.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reference to `[False] * len(image [0])` is repeated `len(image)` times, so modifying the first element of `visited` affects the second (and third).

Comment: That is it. I used to think it would create new `[False] * len(image [0])`. It just creates new reference.